# Prisma transactions suddenly failing constantly

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm using Prisma with Node.js on my server and I'm suddenly getting a lot of errors that say something like this:

`` Error: Invalid `prisma.session.update()` invocation: Transaction failed due to a write conflict or a deadlock. Please retry your transaction at Kr.handleRequestError (/var/www/VLT-express/backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:163:19499) at Kr.handleAndLogRequestError (/var/www/VLT-express/backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:163:19031) at Kr.request (/var/www/VLT-express/backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:163:18869) at async t._request (/var/www/VLT-express/backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:173:9714) ``

I haven't made any changes to the configuration or the codebase itself, and the issue persists even after restarting the server. I do run periodic jobs on the server that send out a fair amount of queries, but I've been running these jobs every 10 minutes for about a month without any issues.

I'm not sure where to begin looking to resolve this issue. Has anyone else run into something similar and have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the query that you are running?